# Using dplyr mutate & ifelse to replace values produces strange output

Tags: r, na, data-cleaning, dplyr

I have a dataframe, WB. On WB I'm using dplyr's mutate() and ifelse() to convert ".." values to the values from adjacent variables.

The solution I've come to is,

```
mutate(WB, Rents2 = ifelse(Rents == "..", `X2014..YR2014.`, Rents)))
```

which produces this output: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GFg5.png

Why does Rents2 return large values instead of the 2014 variable data?

Comment: Please provide your actual data and output rather than a picture.

Comment: None of your variables are numeric.  I would guess they are all factors.  You should reconsider your data import to force anything that is `".."` to `NA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original data was comprised of all factors. Data provider's fields were non-numeric. Solution is to convert data to numeric.